# rc.local runs at wrong time

Tags: server, systemd

I recently installed and set up Ubuntu Server 22.04.03 onto a machine at home. I can SSH into it from my desktop perfectly fine, but I still have a keyboard and monitor attached for the time being.

While this remains the case, I'd like to have it automatically run HTOP (or anything else interesting/pretty, suggestions welcome) and display it on the monitor as soon as its done booting up.

Currently, following advice from another answer here, my `/etc/rc.local` file looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -e
sh '/etc/mainmonitor.sh'
exit 0
```

where `mainmonitor.sh` contains:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
htop
```

I have tried following [this guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd) to create a systemd unit to run rc.local. So the file is executable etc.

Since then I have modified `rc.local.service` slightly based on guesswork and it now looks like this:

```ini
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=simple
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The only real change is `Type=simple` instead of `=forking`, as I unconfidently believe
this tries to start a background process.

Currently this *almost* works. The result is that during boot, a few moments before the login prompt, htop *does start*, however it does not stick around, being immediately overwrote by a few more [OK] lines before finally the screen is wiped and the login prompt shows up (and then cloud-init makes a mess but that's a different problem)

Ultimately I'd like to completely prohibit it from reaching the login prompt and just display htop or whatever I like. If I do need to login directly then I can F10 out of htop and the login screen can show up. I can then confirm from htop through SSH that there's no other htop instance running in the background.

I'm open to complete alternatives to achieve similar results, if `rc.local` isn't viable. I've seen some difficult to comprehend answers regarding autologin but this has issues like not being able to log out as you just get autologged in again... I'm too new to this to resolve that on my own.

This is a home server that will live in my house otherwise only accessible by SSH with keys, so physical security isn't a concern.

Comment: You probably need to look into MOTD ... See for example [UpdateMotd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd) and [`man update-motd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/update-motd.5.html) and also [`man motd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/motd.5.html)

Comment: rc,local is outdated since systemd, which is in Ubuntu since 14.10 / 15.04.
Except this, neither systemd nor rc.local are made to run a program in the foreground. 
If you like to use htop and at the same time have a prompt availble, yoo need to involve screen or tmux or something similar. Plus trigger the start of the program only once logged in.

Comment: I want something to run automatically prior to the local login prompt for the locally connected monitor only. (tty0 I guess?) SSH sessions should be unaffected. I know rc.local is outdated but literally everything I've read around this suggests just turning it on anyway for some reason. I'm really surprised how hard this has been to unpick. I saw something about autologin but that having its own caveats, like not being able to log out again lol. I guess a minimal permssionless user that can just run htop but not make changes would work? but not sure how to enact